# Netbeans: possibility to change the behaviour of getter/setter generation in php module

Tags: php, netbeans, setter, getter-setter

Greetings programmers,

I was wondering if there is a possibility to change the behaviour of getter/setter generation in php module. At the moment it works like this:

```
class A
{
    private $field;
}
```

Now I will generate setter by pressing alt+ins and selecting "Setter..." resulting in:

```
class A
{
    private $field;

    public function setField($field)
    {
         $this->field = $field;
    }
}
```

Is there a possibility to change the behaviour that it would generate something differnet, lets say this:

```
class A
{
    private $field;

    public function setField($field)
    {
         $this->field = $field;
         return $this;
    }
}
```

The difference is at the **returh $this** row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this old question while searching for ways to adjust the template used for setter/getter generation in netbeans.

Since this question is left unanswered, ill leave a pointer to a similar question: [How to edit getter & setter templates in NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636376/how-to-edit-getter-setter-templates-in-netbeans-7-1)

Basically the answer is: No, you can not change the template of the setter/getter generator in netbeans. Atleast not unless you are willing to patch the Netbeans sourcecode.

Comment: Thanks. I have even forgotten about this question. So far it seems that I may switch from netbeans to something different. Anyway, thank you for your time.