# How to edit getter & setter templates in NetBeans?

Tags: templates, netbeans, getter-setter

By default NetBeans generates 3 line getters and setters like so:

```
public int getFoo() {
    return foo;
}
```

Is there a way to make it generate it in one line like so:

```
public int getFoo() {return foo;}
```

I did not find any get or set templates in *Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code Templates*

Is there some other way to edit them or maybe a plugin?

Answer (score 2):

As seem you can't really, but I've found a patch in [this blog post](http://www.fordfrog.com/2010/07/19/modifying-netbeans-generated-getters-and-setters/) which modifies Netbeans source.

Comment: Your link is down for me. The server [can't be found](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://www.fordfrog.name/).

Comment: found a new one, fixed

Answer (score 1):

on NB 7.2+ you can create your own generator:
though making use of Javac API in a NB modules (hard to do something better than a getter/setter)

https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-code-generator.html